# Failed to execute goal... Maven, Heroku Deployment from GitHub

Tags: java, maven, github, heroku

I have problem with Maven pom.xml file that I cannot understand... I created discord bot using java and I want to keep it online 24/7. So I found tutorial how to do it on Heroku using GitHub. And when I deploy project I get this error:

```
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  6.970 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-15T15:44:01Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project gloombot: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Edited: pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gloombot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dv8tion/JDA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-alpha.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Java version from terminal:

```
julibut@Air-Juli gloombot % java -version
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I made screenshots of all things you wanted me to check:

1.[Java Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kQef.png)

2. [Project Modles: Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iApET.png) [Project Settings: Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E6Wb.png)
3. [Java Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUXAA.png)

Comment: I wrote my code in IntelliJ IDEA and it runs well. I have no troubles with maven when run on my pc

Comment: Can you give us more information? pom.xml would be helpful & the java version you're using would be good

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using IntelliJ and I already got this error a few times here is my *TODO* I go through when I get this error:

1. Check Project Version and language level (Project Structure > Project)
2. Do the same for Modules (Project Structure > Modules) **Don't forget the Dependencies Tab** there you can find the module SDK
3. Check Java Compiler (Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler) there you can see a `Project bytecode version` & `Per-module bytecode version` -> Check those

Hope this works :)

Comment: I tried to run commands, but for mvn it doesn't work ;-;

```julibut@Air-Juli gloombot % java -version

openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)

julibut@Air-Juli gloombot % mvn -version

zsh: command not found: mvn

julibut@Air-Juli gloombot % 
```

Comment: I attached pom.xml file as you asked

Comment: Yeah I changed my answer. When this doesn't work my guess is that something is wrong with you're mvn maybe check JAVA_HOME environment variable too

Comment: I checked all this stuff and seems like version of Java is correct... Like I said, code is being run successfully in IntelliJ, but when I am trying to connect it to Heroku from GitHub, where I imported my project, it fails :( Anyway thank you for help!

Comment: There is also 1 thing I am doubted in is `<maven.compiler.source>17<maven.compiler.source>` Because many users that upload their pom files have versions 1.5.-1.8

Comment: do you have a system.properties file? with `java.runtime.version=17`

Comment: Erm... no... I remember this is specifying type of java version in gradle, right?

Comment: Actually now I am trying to put instead of 17 number 1.8 and instead of this error I receive errors with recognizing switch cycles that work with -> {}. Maybe if I rewrite code for older versions of java it will work...

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version. They also have a list of supported java versions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions

Comment: Maybe I should've type 17.0.3 instead of 17. They have table there and one row is
OpenJDK 17 17.0.3 17.0.3 17.0.3
Anyway now I have typed 1.8 and rewrited some code and it is deployed successfully. Only doesn't work but it is another problem :D